# Return data from multiple vertices in a single nested object

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi, gremlinpython

I am trying to return a single nested object which combines data from multiple vertices using Gremlin.

Example Data Model:

[image: Data Model]

For the above data model I would like to return a list of externalReferences for a given referenceSignal and system.

I have been able to return the vertices I want data from by using `.select()` steps but I am unsure how I can manipulate the returned vertices into one single object.

Current query:

```
g.V().has('id', 'SYSTEM_ID').hasLabel('system').as("system")
.in("partOf").hasLabel('component').as("component")
.in("partOf").hasLabel('signal').as("signal")
.where(out("instanceOf").hasLabel('referenceSignal').has("name", "REF_SIGNAL_NAME")).in("describes").hasLabel('externalReference').as("externalReference")

.select('system', 'component', 'signal', 'externalReference')
```

Output:

```
[{system=v[2776], component=v[2780], signal=v[2797], externalReference=v[2843]}, {system=v[2776], component=v[2785], signal=v[2802], externalReference=v[2848]}]
```

I want the returned data to be in the follow format:

```
{
"system_id": "{system_id from the system vertex}",
"system_name": "{system_name from the system vertex}",
"components": [ # Array of components adjacent to system
    { 
      "component_id": "{component_id from the component vertex}",
      "component_name": "{component_name from the component vertex}",
      "signals": [ # Array of signals adjacent to component
        {
          "signal_id": "{signal_id from the signal vertex}",
          "signal_name": "{signal_name from the signal vertex}",
          "external_reference_id": "{external_reference_id from the external reference vertex adjacent to the signal}"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can use the project() step with by() modulators, see https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#project-step The by() step for the signal vertices can contain an anonymous traversal that does a nested project() step for the signal properties.

Comment: Thanks @HadoopMarc, since posting the question I have been able to get closer to what I want using ` .by(valueMap('id', 'name'))` tempted to do the remaining transformation within the application rather than by the gremlin query